# Prove: There is no $r\in \mathbb{Q}: r^{n}=p$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, p is prime

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Let assume that there is such $r\in \mathbb{Q}$, and that $r$ is irreducible fraction $\frac{m}{z}$.

$r^n=(\frac{m}{z})^n=p\iff \frac{m^n}{z^n}=p \iff m^n=p*z^n$

Because $m^n$ can be divided by $p$ so does $m$ (because all integers are multiplication of primes).

So $m$ can be written as $m=p*k$, putting it back to the equation we get $(p*k)^n=p*z^n\iff p^{n-1}*k^n=z^n$

So $z^n$ can be divided by $p^{n-1}$ and in particular $z$ can be divided by $p$ (because all integers are multiplication of primes).

So we got $m=p*k$ and $z=p*q$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $\frac{m}{n}$ is a irreducible fraction.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Your question being?

Comment: 2 is a prime number in Q. Take n = 1.

Comment: @Mandrathax sorry, added, I want to know if the proof is written correctly

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk do you mean that the proof does not work for $n=1$ and $p=2$?

Comment: Elsewhere you can get immediately after taking n-root ($n\ne 1$) that an irrational is equal to a rational which is absurde.

Comment: If $n>1$ will it fix it?

Comment: @gbox What I meant is that all prime number are in Q already so if you don't constrict yourself to $n>1$ then there is nothing to prove.
If $n>1$ then I'm still having trouble with the step where you claim that n is divisible by p because $n^n$ is divisible by $p^{n-1}$. I can't prove right now that it is wrong, but it feels wrong. Also avoid using n twice :).

Comment: @lhf I have change $n$ with $z$ for easier reading

Comment: Issue with n = 1 still stands. Take m = p, z = 1, n = 1 and we have an r in Q such that r^n = p.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk so the qeustion in the book have an error, if we demand $n>1$ it is ok?

Comment: That or r needs to be in Q\N... What book is it?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk the book is not written in English, but I have sent an email to the editor

Comment: You should extend the problem by trying to show that if $ r\in \mathbb{Q}, m $ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then

$r^n=m \Rightarrow r\in \mathbb{N}$